# Removing duplicates from array and ordering by something

Tags: java, xml

I have a java object, which outputs my xml data. My goal is to remove duplicates in array and sort by birth date(oldest first etc.) Currently i don't have an idea, how to do those. Could you guys help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JAXB` to convert this XML into java object. And then you can sort them based on your own criteria's by implementing `Comparable` interface.

EDIT: 
If you have XSD, use xjc compiler to convert xsd to java classes. And then use those classes in JAXB.

Step 1 :

Use xjc command to create java classes from xsd. Go to directory where your xsd is saved. And open command prompt / terminal and fire below command.

```
xjc your_xsd.xsd
```

Some classes will generate in the directory. Not all are necessary but one with member variables used to denote xml node is important. Copy that into your project src files.
Suppose that class name is `DataDocument`.

And then your java class which will do unmarshaliing will be like :

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    try {
        File xmlFile = new File("your_xml_file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbCtx = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataDocument.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbCtx.createUnmarshaller();
        DataDocument dataDocument = (DataDocument) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
        System.out.println("data document is : " + dataDocument);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
       e.printStackTrace ();
    }
}
```

Change code as per your needs.

Comment: Are you able to get java object from XML?

Comment: i cannot compile because of line:
Isik isik = (Isik) element.getValue ();

Isik cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: probably I cannot resolve isik, because of wrong import on the first line(import generated.Isik;).

Comment: could you please give me some code example? im not very familiar with XSD and compilers..

Comment: @Üllar See updates. And make sure your XSD is valid. I guess it's not.

Comment: cmd: xjc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file.

Comment: i checked XSD validation and its valid.

Comment: may be on windows machine xjc is not available. Try it on linux.

Comment: Just checked on peers machine and found that xjc command is available on windows as well. Check your environmental variables. http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/07/invoking_xjc_fr.html

Comment: i just replaced all previous code to the original one i have. I got all my data outputted, without comparision. But the problem right now is, that i have 3 for loops. Do you know how i can get those all in one loop?

Comment: iterate it. for(YourObject obj : yourList) {}

Comment: I finally got it right. You can look up my code above.. If you have any ideas, how to remove duplicates from the array, or how to sort by bdate, let me know ;) You have given me a lot of help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Castor Framework for converting from an XML to Java Object